# set value to row in grid in extjs 3.4

Tags: extjs, set, record

i have an editorgrid with two actioncolumns each consisting of forms in two windows.When I enter data in the forms(single field for each window),i want that data to get set in the value set in the dataIndex property of the grid store.The grid may have multiple rows and thus multiple data.How to set particular data of particular grid to the gridstore so that it can be passed to server?

Answer (score 0):

Find and set changed record clicked from `actioncolumn`:

```
//Each action column has handler configuration option that has all you need
handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
    // the target record
    var rec = store.getAt(rowIndex);
    // then you can change the record/pass it further opening windows
    // changes made on the record would be reflected inside grid's store    
}
```

[Ext.grid.ActionColumn docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.ActionColumn)

To update grid's modified records you could run:

```
gridStore.commitChanges()
```

[Ext.data.Store#commitChanges](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-commitChanges) (could be useful to look at the Proxy [Ext.data.HttpProxy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.HttpProxy))

or do it yourself manually, using the store `modified` records array [getModifiedRecords](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getModifiedRecords).

P.S. will be helpful to explorer Ext 3.4 Data Package.